# Exception while trying to log in using spring security version 5.4.6 and java 12

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, maven, spring-security

I have a web application where I have been used.

```
org.springframework-version: 4.1.4.RELEASE
spring.security.version: 3.2.5.RELEASE
org.hibernate-version: 3.5.1-Final.
java-version 1.6
```

I'm trying to upgrade the spring, java, and the hibernate version where I successfully updated the following in my pom file

```
org.springframework-version: 5.3.6
spring.security.version: 5.4.6
org.hibernate-version: 5.4.31.Final
java-version -version: 11.0.2
```

And I have also updated the related XML file where I mentioned the spring security beans. I'm using Postgres DB. I'm facing an issue. When I entered the username and password, and when I click on the submit button, it shows a 405 error page. No error messages are showing on the console.

beans in my spring-security.xml file

```
<form-login login-page="/login" login-processing-url="/login" default-target-url="/"
            authentication-failure-url="/login?error" username-parameter="username"
            password-parameter="password" />
        <logout logout-success-url="/" invalidate-session="false"/>
        
        <beans:bean id="daoAuthenticationProvider"
 class="org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider">
  <beans:property name="userDetailsService" ref="userDetailsService"/>
</beans:bean>

<beans:bean id="authenticationManager"
    class="org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager">
 <beans:constructor-arg> 
    <beans:list>
      <beans:ref bean="daoAuthenticationProvider" />
    </beans:list>
  </beans:constructor-arg>
</beans:bean>


    <!-- Declare an authentication-manager to use a custom userDetailsService -->
    <authentication-manager>
        <authentication-provider user-service-ref="userDetailsService">
        <password-encoder hash="bcrypt" />
        </authentication-provider>
    </authentication-manager>
```

My userServiceImpl

```
@Service("userDetailsService")
public class UserServiceImpl implements UserDetailsService, UserService {
@Transactional(readOnly = true)
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String userName) throws UsernameNotFoundException, DataAccessException {

        String siteDomainName = (String) request.getServerName();
        logger.info("A user trying to login in domainnName " + siteDomainName+" with username/email "+userName);
        Site site = null;
        try {
            <!-- codes-->
        } catch (SiteManagerException e) {
            <!--error message-->
        }
        
    }
```

Login controller

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/login", method = RequestMethod.GET)
        public String login(ModelMap model, @RequestParam(value = "error", required = false) String error, @RequestParam(value = "logout", required = false) String logout)
        {
            try
            {
                 <!-- codes-->
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                <!--error message-->
            }
        }
```

Can anyone help me to solve this? Thanks

Error while login

```
20210610-09:25:25.108 sitepm-service [http-nio-8036-exec-9] ERROR o.h.e.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.logExceptions - This method is not yet implemented.

20210610-09:25:25.108 sitepm-admin [http-nio-8036-exec-9] ERROR o.h.e.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.logExceptions - This method is not yet implemented.
20210610-09:25:25.110 sitepm-service [http-nio-8036-exec-9] ERROR c.s.a.u.controller.LoginController.setExceptionPage - org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not prepare statement

20210610-09:25:25.110 sitepm-admin [http-nio-8036-exec-9] ERROR c.s.a.u.controller.LoginController.setExceptionPage - org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not prepare statement
```

Comment: Do you use GET or POST for logging in?

Comment: @dan1st No, I'm not using a POST method for logging in. Using a GET method to load the login page.

Comment: Try using post as spring security expects post by default.

Comment: @dan1st I'm using POST method on the login page FTL, I have added the login page FTL above. Also, added the login controller.

Comment: What is the HTTP request that returns a 405?

Comment: @jzheaux That issue is resolved and I'm able to login in locally. But in the QA environment not able to log in showing an error (error added on the above).
`